# Click Event Propagation with Multiple Nested Children

Tags: javascript, html, event-propagation

In the following code, when I click on any element, I only see one event fired (logged in the console) per click. From what I've read, I thought I should see a console log for every element that is under where the mouse click happened because of event propagation and bubbling. It seems like I only get an event for the most deeply nested element, though.

How can I determine, for example, when clicking on a button, what is the ID of the button that was clicked, since the event target is always the child image. Do I just have to live with knowing the HTML structure, and asking for e.target.parentNode or is there a more elegant way to access an intermediate node in the event propagation tree?

```js
document.getElementById('parent')
.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName + ' ' + e.target.id);
});
```

```css
#parent {
  border: thin black solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#child1, #child2 {
  border: thin green solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#btn1, #btn2 {
  border: thin red solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#image1, #image2 {
  width: 100%;  
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <button id="btn1">
      <img id="image1" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    <button id="btn2">
      <img id="image2" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Event propagation only means that, when you click (say) on an element, the `click` handlers of that element and all its parents are executed in turn. But in your example only the `#parent` has a handler, so only one `console.log` is ever executed. I'm also confused by your question about how to get the ID of the button, because that's exactly what it's showing you in your example.

Comment: @RobinZigmond... two things: Why does the target end up being BUTTON instead of, say, IMG? And, second, I guess what I was expecting / wanting was to put a single click handler on the parent div, and then get it called multiple times with the target elements being each of the children of the parent that were under where the click happened, so that I could consolidate logic in one place and decide what to do based on the nodeType of the target. Event propagation is probably the wrong term for this, maybe event delegation, or something else entirely?

Comment: "Why does the target end up being BUTTON instead of, say, IMG?". I actually get IMG displayed every time I click on the button-with-image, never BUTTON. (And this makes sense since the image has height and width 100%, so it takes up exactly the same area.) As for the other question, I still don't really follow what you're trying to do - but as your example shows, you can indeed get information about the target, just from a single handler in the parent. Doesn't this mean you can already "consolidate logic in one place" and "decide what to do based on the nodeType of the target"?